# Lie algebra of operators isomorphic to some matrix Lie subgroup

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

$V=\left\{a\partial_x+bx+cI:a,b,c\in\mathbb{C}\right\}$ with $[X,Y]:=XY-YX$

**Question 1**. $V$ with $[X,Y]$ is a Lie álgebra with dimension 3, right?

By Ado's theorem, the Lie Álgebra $V$  is isomorphic to a Lie subalgebra of the square matrix space $M(n,\mathbb{R})$ some $n$ (this is what I have been able to understand)

**Question 2**. What would be the matrix Lie subalgebra that is isomorphic to $V$?

Comment: Is $[X,Y]:=XY-YX$

 All complex 3
-dimensional Lie algebras are classified and have known matrix representations. Why? Some reference?

Comment: Why? This is basic Lie theory. For a reference see for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2101530/classification-of-3-dimensional-lie-algebra), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3163530/classification-of-lie-algebras-of-dim-3). Can you fill in the Lie brackets? What is $[\partial_x,x]$ for example?

Comment: $[\partial_x,x]=1$

Comment: In your space $V$, I suppose $I=1$, right? And what is $[\partial_x, I]$ and $[x,I]$?

Comment: $[\partial_x,I]=\partial_x I-I\partial_x=0$ and $[x,I]=xI-Ix=0$? right?

Comment: If so, then you are done. The Lie brackets are exactly the ones of the Heisenberg Lie algebra. It has a very famous faithful matrix representation, see [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg-Algebra).

Answer (score 1):

We have answered the question together in the comments. You don't need Ado's theorem.

Let $(e_1,e_2,e_3)=(\partial_x,x,I)$ be a basis of $L$.
Then $[e_1,e_2]=e_3$ and $[e_1,e_3]=[e_2,e_3]=0$. Hence $L$ is the Heisenberg Lie algebra, with underlying vector space $V$.

It has a faithful matrix representation $\rho\colon L\hookrightarrow \mathfrak{gl}_3(\Bbb C)$, given by
$$
    \rho(e_1)={\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\\\end{pmatrix}},\quad \rho(e_2)={\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\\\end{pmatrix}},\quad \rho(e_3)={\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\\\end{pmatrix}}.
$$
The image is isomorphic to the Lie subalgebra of strictly upper-triangular matrices.

Comment: I see. What I want to understand now is: how is that application defined $\rho$ etc. Where does it come from? I'll have to read the theory

Comment: How is this matrix representation obtained?

Comment: By knowing the Lie algebra of strictly lower-triangular matrices. It is nilpotent, and it is easy to see what the Lie brackets are. On the other hand, one can just compute matrices $\rho(e_i)$ satisfying $\rho([e_i,e_j])=[\rho(e_i),\rho(e_j)]$.

Comment: Yes. I saw it seconds later, so I deleted the comment. thank you so much